# Align elements in div

Tags: css, html, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have 3 `div`s in a container.

I want the left one (green) to be anchored (with some offset) to the left-bottom corner, the middle element (red) docked to the left element and centered vertically, and the right one (blue) to be docked to the right but centered vertically.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shimmy/A3Me9/) I'm working on.

I tried using `right` and `margin-right` etc. but it didn't work, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shimmy/drrz6/) are some of my attempts.

This is the initial setup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
</div>
.container {
    background: gray;    
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
.container > div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;       
}
div.left {
    background: green;
    height: 250px;
}
div.middle {
    background: red;
}
div.right {
    background: blue;
}
```

Result: 
[image]

Comment: Could you please add your relevant code (HTML and CSS) to your question, and, ideally, show us an image so we can visualise your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed the fiddle based on your comments. Is this what you desire? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3Me9/5/)

*I've updated the fiddle

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    background: gray;    
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
.container > div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;       
}
.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 250px !important;
    background: green;
}
.middle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    bottom: calc(50% - 50px);
    background: red;
}
.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: calc(50% - 50px);
    background: blue;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3Me9/5/)

Comment: No, the red div should be docked to the right of the green div, not above it. I've updated the question a bit, the green div should be a little higher, say 250px, and docked to the bottom-left, so it's more clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to retain the float layout (i.e. left and middle will not overlap each other), the solution is to wrap the inner content of each div with another `<div>` element, and position them absolutely with respect to their floated parents: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/drrz6/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"><div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle"><div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right"><div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For your CSS:

```
.container {
    background: gray;    
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
.container > div {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.container > div > div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
    .left > div {
        background: green;
        bottom: 0;
    }
.middle {
    float: left;
}
    .middle > div {
        background: red;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -50px; /* Half of height */
    }
.right {
    float: right;
}
    .right > div {
        background: blue;    
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

Comment: I don't have to retain the code. I just need the desired outcome. I've updated the question a bit, the green div should be a little higher, say 250px, and docked to the bottom-left. You're almost there but isn't it too much CSS? isn't there a cleaner solution?

Comment: @Shimmy Did you check the fiddle I posted?

Comment: Yes. We're almost there, I'm just unable to set the green's height to 250px, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/shimmy/NgLvT, besides in my real scenario I have many elements and I don't like wrapping all of them in redundant divs, I prefer using different means (i.e. other than float), but the code should be cleaner.

Comment: That is due to specificity of CSS: `.container > div > div` is more specific than `.left > div`. Therefore, to override styles specified in the former, update the latter's selector to `.container > .left > div` http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/NgLvT/1/

Comment: Well, the result is what I desire. Anyway [this](http://jsfiddle.net/shimmy/j5yAH/) could be even better, if I could only set the vertical alignment without adding extra elements, I'm sure there is a way. Maybe `display: table`?

Comment: It will not work, because you are floating the elements. Floated elements do not work with CSS table displays. The nesting is unavoidable because of your requirements... if you can think of a way to do so without that additional `<div>` nesting, I'm all ears.

Comment: I added a new answer. I'm using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use flex boxes:

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/fr9U5/

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="middle">middle</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 270px;
    height:210px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
    -moz-box-direction: reverse;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
    -ms-flex-direction: column-reverse;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -moz-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: gray;
}
.left {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-item-align: start;
    align-self: flex-start;
    background-color: green;
}
.middle {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    -ms-flex-item-align: center;
    align-self: center;
    background-color: red;
}
.right {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-item-align: end;
    align-self: flex-end;
    background-color: blue;
}
/*
    Legacy Firefox implementation treats all flex containers
    as inline-block elements.
*/
 @-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .flex-container {
        width: 100%;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }
}
.box > div {
    border:1px solid #000;
    width: 33%;
    height:33%;
}
```

Comment: Great. But I need support for older browsers. Yikes!

Answer (score 0):

OK. I guess the `position:absolute` is what works best for me, although I'd prefer the middle (red) element to depend on the left (green) one.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/shimmy/WW34Z/) is the solution, and thanks [Terry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23281487/75500) for the tip on deducting half-size of self to center vertically.

```
.container {
    background: gray;    
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.container > div {    
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;       
    position: absolute;
}
div.left {    
    background: green;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;    
    height: 250px;
}
div.middle {    
    background: red;
    left: 100px;
    bottom: 0;    
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; //deduct lalfsize of self

}
div.right {
    background: blue;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; //deduct lalfsize of self
}
```